# Data Analytics: Word2Vec vs TFIDF

Tags: python, classification, vectorization, word2vec, tf-idf

I would like to analyze a huge amount of data and classify it.
The data are labeled text information.
For this operation I need a vectorizer.

Which one would you prefer? Word2Vec or TFIDF
I tried both bot can not really see the advantages/disadvantages from each of them.

Comment: Could you tell us the nature of your dataset and what you are trying to do with it, because each of these have their own advantages and disadvantages for different uses.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid asking recommendation questions. It would be helpful if you could post info on the dataset, the code you've tried and your desired output.

Comment: They're both easy to try, so try them both on your data/goals, & pick the one that scores better on your repeatable evaluation.